# install4j: "Execute launcher" action doesn't work for "Require administrator" Execution level

Tags: install4j

We have "Generated launcher" with "Execution Level" set to "Require administrator". We install our application to "Program Files" folder and request privileges during installation process.
On the Finish form we have a "Run application" checkbox and "Execute launcher" action.
When we migrated from 7.0.7 to 8.0.8 the "Execute launcher" action fails with the following  error in logs:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.ExecuteLauncherAction [ID 1746]: Execute action
       Property arguments: null
       Property launcherId: 18
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       execute directly
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\app\app.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\app"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.ExecuteLauncherAction [ID 1746]: Execute action not successful after 27 ms
```

The "C:\Program Files\app" folder is created with our application content and it's possible to run the application manually. We have to run the application with administrative rights in the "Program Files" folder.

When I set the installation folder to a user home and change "Execution level" to "As invoker" - the application starts successfully without any exceptions.

How is it possible to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ingo Kegel's answer we need use "Run executable" action and set "Action elevation type" property to "Elevate to maximum available privileges".

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Action elevation type" property of the "Execute launcher" action to "Elevate to maximum available privileges". Then the launcher is started by the elevated helper process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't help. I see the same error in log:
`[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\app\app.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\app"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.ExecuteLauncherAction [ID 1746]: Execute action not successful after 30 ms`
May be this could help: I've also migrated to JRE 11.

Comment: Can you try with the "Run executable" action instead?

Comment: This works, thank you! Is this a bug with "Execute launcher" action?

Comment: The "Execute launcher" action indeed always starts the launcher in unelevated mode, this has historical reasons. In install4j 9 we will have it automatically start launchers in elevated mode if they require elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add your answer as question answer.